# Docker Swarm Placement Constrains Not Working

Tags: mysql, wordpress, docker, docker-compose, docker-swarm

I have a Docker Swarm Cluster with one manager node and three workers. I'm deploying a docker-compose WordPress and MySQL and there are two rules for this deployment:

- There will be no service on the manager node
- WordPress and MySQL services should not be in the same node together

I tried labels to prevent the MySQL service from being deployed in the same node as the WordPress services and it's not working

This is my docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.3'

services:
   db:
     image: mysql:5.7
     volumes:
       - db_data:/var/lib/mysql
     restart: always
     environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: somewordpress
       MYSQL_DATABASE: wordpress
       MYSQL_USER: wordpress
       MYSQL_PASSWORD: wordpress
     deploy:
       labels: [region=database]
       placement:
         constraints: 
           - node.role == worker

   wordpress:
     depends_on:
       - db
     image: wordpress:latest
     ports:
       - "8000:80"
     restart: always
     environment:
       WORDPRESS_DB_HOST: db:3306
       WORDPRESS_DB_USER: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD: wordpress
       WORDPRESS_DB_NAME: wordpress
     deploy:
       mode: replicated
       replicas: 2
       placement:
         constraints: 
           - node.role == worker
           - node.labels.region != database
volumes:
    db_data: {}
```

I use this command for deployment

```
sudo docker stack deploy --compose-file docker-compose.yml stackdemo
```

However, I still see that sometimes the MySQL service and one of the WordPress services are running in the same node and keep the third server empty!

How can I prevent that from happening? Is there any other way or are there any problems with my constraints?